# Spring JDBC - throw custom exception instead of DataAccessException

Tags: java, spring, exception, jdbctemplate

For DAO I use spring jdbcTemplate and I need to throw my own custom exception instead of standard spring DataAccessException. And I cannot extend DataAccessException because I have my own exception hierarchy.

So I wrote code like this:

```
public class CustomSQLErrorTranslator extends SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator {

    protected DataAccessException customTranslate(String task, String sql, SQLException sqlex) {
        throw new RepositoryException(task + "; query ->" + sql, sqlex);
    }

}
```

This method should return any child of DataAccessException of null. But instead I throw my custom exception.

It works but it's clearly a hack...

Is it safe? Or maybe I'm missing another way to do this?

Comment: **My greatest fear is that at some point spring will stop rolling back runtime exceptions** test your code yourself first, see if it failures or not?